# pythonQt catching non integer input

Tags: python

Hi are just having a problem catching the instance when a letter rather than a number is entered by the user. Get error 'can't assign number to function call'

It's a simple two QLine Edit boxes where the user has to guess the number...any help would be appreciated. Have just posted the function bit

```
 def my_response():
        global counter, random_number
        timer=QtCore.QTimer

        try:
            reply.text()= int(reply.text())

            if int(reply.text()) <self. random_number:
                question.setText("Your guess is too low. Please Try Again")
                reply.setText(" ")


            elif int(reply.text()) >self. random_number:
                question.setText("Your guess is too high. Please Try Again")
                reply.setText(" ")


            elif int(reply.text()) ==self. random_number:
                question.setStyleSheet('QLineEdit{color: blue}')
                question.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Stencil", 15, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
                question.setText("Correct")
                timer.singleShot(250,lambda:question.setText('You won'))
                reply.setText(" ")

        except:
            reply.setText('invalad input number is needed')
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is at

```
reply.text()= int(reply.text())
```

The message is straightforward - you can't assign number to function call. (Actually, you can't assign anything to function call.)

Note also, that you can assign `inputMask` or `validator` to your QLineEdit and you won't have to check for invalid input at all.